# HTML5 required stops ASP:Button from working

Tags: asp.net, html

I am trying to click on an ASP:Button with an onclick function. Every time I do that the HTML5 Required stops the click from occurring. I even tried to include an ASP:UpdatePanel but that does not work neither.

```
    <form id="form1" name="theform" class="form-horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="fb_login" runat="server">
                <asp:button CssClass="btn-facebook" ID="FacebookButton" Text="Login with Facebook" OnClick="FacebookButton_Click" runat="server" />
            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                            <div>
                            <input type="text" tabindex="1" class="form-control" id="FirstName" required title="Enter First Name" runat="server" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                            <div>
                            <input type="text" tabindex="2" class="form-control" id="LastName" required title="Enter Last Name" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Information</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: For future reference, UpdatePanels are the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the UpdatePanel and set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on FacebookButton:

```
<asp:button UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btn-facebook" ID="FacebookButton" Text="Login with Facebook" OnClick="FacebookButton_Click" runat="server" />
```